# Is there a way to change a file's extension to .txt, copy the text to a new file, and change back to the original format without breaking the file?

Tags: encryption, file-extension

So I know that this is going to sound like kind of an odd question, but the reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to encrypt a powerpoint presentation, just for fun.

I know that if you change a file's extension to .txt that you can open it up in a text editor, and I think it wouldn't be too hard to encrypt the file's contents at this point.  My plan was to send the encrypted text file (that was originally a powerpoint) to a friend, along with a program that would display the decrypted text in a terminal, if my friend provided the correct decryption key.  My thought was that my friend could then copy this decrypted text to a new file, and rename it to .pptx in order to view the presentation. (I agree that this seems like an odd way to do it, but I think it is the best way for my situation.)

However, if the text is copied to a different file which is then renamed to be a .pptx file, powerpoint declares it as broken.  I am positive that I copied all of the text, the exact way that it was in the original file.  Why is it that this doesn't work?  And is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption using standard/modern cryptographic algorithms requires the data to be binary. The `.pptx` format seems to be zip compressed XML. This means it is already binary.

If you open it in a text editor (without decompression) it is very likely that you loose information as not all bytes will translate into displayable characters. Text editors don't have anything to do with encryption, so I don't understand that step.

You can also open any file in a text editor if you so please. Renaming it to `.txt` only has the effect that the default text editor is used when you double click (or "start") the document.

Answer (score 1):

Although a fun idea, changing the extension is not enough. A good portion of the ppt file will not 'translate' properly. You can actually open any file type in notepad (in fact file extensions don't actually mean anything. It's just a little tag so your OS knows how to interpret it.) You could however write a PDF file which identically represents your powerpoint (as long as there is no animation) in LaTeX and encrypt the source code and have him decrypt it using the same algorithm.

tldr; won't work how you'd like it to. you would have to find other means to encrypt the file.